# disable closing popup when clicking on background

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I use featherlight.js for lightbox. When it is opened and I click on it's background it cloeses popup. I need to disable this functionality. I noticed that this js has closeTrigger option in it but don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default option in it:

```
 closeOnClick: false           /* Close lightbox on click ('background', 'anywhere', or false) */
```

Select "FALSE" value this will disable the closing of popup on clicking on background.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest not to write javascript snippet separately as you already using **"data" attributes** to initialise the lightbox.

As per documentation provided, you can set **data-featherlight-close-on-click="false"** in markup itself to achieve the same.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/c5pq5bs1/2/

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-featherlight-close-on-click="false" data-featherlight="#fl1">Default</a>
<div class="lightbox" id="fl1">
    <h2>Featherlight Default</h2>
    <p>
        This is a default featherlight lightbox.<br>
        It's flexible in height and width.<br>
        Everything that is used to display and style the box can be found in the 
    </p>
    <a href="https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/blob/master/src/featherlight.css">featherlight.css</a> file which is pretty simple.
</div>
```

With this option, you will save writing separate script block just to enable this feature.

Comment: It is working fine. Thanks Bro..

Answer (score 1):

In documentation, you can disable it from its defaults

```
defaults: {
      closeOnClick: false, /* Close lightbox on click ('background', 'anywhere', or false) */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks, I found solution after writing my question, but thanks everyone. My final code looks in this way:

```
jQuery.featherlight(jQuery('#professional_investor_box'), {
        closeOnClick:false,
});
```