# featherlight.js configuration options for close

Tags: featherlight.js

I am trying to figure out how to use the close configuration option but it is not working.  Here is my code:

```
<a href="assets/img/photo.png" data-featherlight="image" data-featherlight-closeOnClick= "background" >Open Image</a>
```

I am new to this, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable closing popup when clicking on background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938584/disable-closing-popup-when-clicking-on-background)

Answer (score 1):

Featherlight follows conventions: use `data-featherlight-close-on-click`